# Save iteration number during a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I have a list of arrays that I am iterating over with python, so the head of my loop looks like:

```
for item in my_long_list:
     do_something
```

My problem is that I want to save the iteration number, so that info can be extracted from another array, something like:

```
for item in my_long_list:
    do_something
    grab_values(another_long_list[i])
```

where `i` is he iteration number that the loop is going through at that moment.

I thought about doing a nested loop like:

```
for i in list(range(1,len(my_long_list)):
    for item in my_long_list:
        do_something
        grab_values(another_long_list[i])
```

but it repeats `i` for each one of the `items`, when in reality what I want is one single iteration number per item in my long list.

So is there a way to "store" the iteration number and use it within the loop with python?

Comment: I think you are talking about the enumerate function https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html

Comment: @Mntfr yes, indeed! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `enumerate` method that returns the tuple of item number and value.

```
for iter, i in enumerate(my_long_list)):
    for item in my_long_list:
        do_something
        grab_values(another_long_list[iter])
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want current item number, maybe you can do this:

```
for i, v in enumerate(my_long_list,1): # item number from 1 start
    do_something
    grab_values(another_long_list[i])
```